# How does the R `+` operator know to behave differently depending on class?

Tags: r, lubridate

Here's a method from the `lubridate` package.

```r
> getMethod("month<-")
Method Definition (Class "derivedDefaultMethod"):

  function (x, value)
  {
    if (!is.numeric(value)) {
      value <- pmatch(tolower(value), c("january", "february",
                                        "march", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october",
                                        "november", "december"))
    }
    x <- x + months(value - month(x))
  }
```

My question is the last line with the `+` operator. The operator behaves differently depending on the class of `x`. How does R know to do this? How do I see the source code for `+`?

```r
> library(lubridate)
> 
> customFUN <- function (x, value){
+   x <- x + months(value - month(x))
+   return(x)
+ }
> 
> 
> init_datePOSIX <- as.POSIXct("2017-11-01")
> init_dateDate <- as.Date("2017-11-01")
> 
> customFUN(init_datePOSIX, 12)
[1] "2017-11-01 PDT"
> customFUN(init_dateDate, 12)
[1] "2017-12-01"
```

My session info:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.3.3   yaml_2.2.0    Rcpp_1.0.0    stringi_1.3.2 stringr_1.3.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` operator is really just like any other function, and can be treated as such.

You can see the source code for `+` by typing:

```
`+`
```

Furthermore, you can see the various methods for `+` by typing:

```
methods(`+`)
```

When a function is called, the class of the object is checked to see what method should be called. When multiple classes exist, the first matching method will be taken from the classes.

You can therefore define your own methods for `+`

```
`+.custom` <- function(e1, e2) {
  paste0(e1, e2)
}

x <- 1
class(x) <- c("custom", "numeric")

x + x
```

Here, we overode the classes for `x` to include an *additional* class `"custom"`, and you can see that the behavior defaults to the newly defined `+.custom`.

However, the value will still work as normal (numeric) for other methods yet to be defined, try this code for example:

```
x / 10 * 500
```

---

**Additional reading:** https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/UseMethod.html

Comment: How do I get the source code for this method: `+,POSIXct,Period-method`.

Comment: reading `getAnywhere("+.POSIXt")` should be sufficient to see that it behaves based on inheritance of additional classes.

Comment: `help("groupGeneric")` is also relevant.